# Django settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER problem

Tags: django, email, settings

I need some help regarding django emailing. I have set the
settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER to 'do-not-re...@mysite.com' and whenever I
am trying to send an email in any context, its taking the 'do-not-
re...@mysite.com' as from address and sending it, eventhough I supply
a different from-address while sending that specific email. How do I
fix this?

Answer (score 1):

EMAIL_HOST_USER is only used for authentication on the mail server.

You probably need to also set DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL.

Comment: In my case DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL is also set to EMAIL_HOST_USER. But having a case where any website user sends an message(from his email-id) to some other user, is so common. So why wouldn't django allow that. And certainly it has to be different from website's DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL or EMAIL_HOST_USER!.

Comment: Maddy, can you show me the source code line where you are sending the email?  The standard django send_mail function has an argument for the from address, so I would need to see your code to answer further.  Thanks!